# What can I do to make webGazer active when the web page is displayed on a tablet?

Tags: javascript

Good afternoon,

I find myself developing an application for tablet, which will provide several photos for the user to look at, and whose look will be detected with WebGazer. After the first tests I did with the pages I have as a base for the application, I realized when testing on my tablet, that it was not active, despite working on the pc. The test pages are in HTML5 and WebGazer is being called in main.js. Below I leave the call function of webGazer.

```
webgazer.setGazeListener(function(data, elapsedTime) {

  //Esconde a imagem do ecrã
  $("#webgazerVideoFeed").hide();
  $("#webgazerFaceOverlay").hide();
  $("#webgazerFaceFeedbackBox").hide();

  //Passa para full screen
  if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
    document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
    document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen();
  }

  // Bloqueio da orientação do ecrã no formato landscape
  screen.orientation.lock('landscape');

  //Funcionamento para a página de fotografia horizontal
  if (document.querySelector('.general-content2') !== null) {

      /*Fotografia Horizontal -------------------------------------------*/
    //constates que representam os selectores de cada uma dos quadrados no qual o ecrã se encontra dividido
      const caixaEsquerdaCima = document.querySelector('#caixa-esquerda-cima');
      const caixaMeioCima = document.querySelector('#caixa-meio-cima');
      const caixaDireitaCima = document.querySelector('#caixa-direita-cima');
      const caixaEsquerdaBaixo = document.querySelector('#caixa-esquerda-baixo');
      const caixaMeioBaixo = document.querySelector('#caixa-meio-baixo');
      const caixaDireitaBaixo = document.querySelector('#caixa-direita-baixo');

      //alert('It exists');
      if (data == null) {
        return;
      }
      //quando o tracker do WebGazer não se encontra em cima do quadrado, este não apresenta cor nenhuma, ou seja, volta a estar transparente
      caixaEsquerdaCima.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
      caixaMeioCima.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
      caixaDireitaCima.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
      caixaEsquerdaBaixo.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
      caixaMeioBaixo.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
      caixaDireitaBaixo.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';

      //Se o y< ecrã /2 significa que está na parte de cima 
      if (data.y <= window.innerHeight / 2)
      {
        if (data.x <= window.innerWidth / 2) 
        {
          caixaEsquerdaCima.style.backgroundColor = 'tomato'
        } 
        else if (data.x >= (2 * window.innerWidth) / 3) 
        {
          caixaDireitaCima.style.backgroundColor = 'tomato'
        }
        else
        {
          caixaMeioCima.style.backgroundColor = 'tomato'
        }

      } 
      //Se o y > ecrã /2 significa que está na parte de cima 
      else
      {
        if (data.x <= window.innerWidth / 4) 
        {
          caixaEsquerdaBaixo.style.backgroundColor = 'tomato'
        } 
        else if (data.x >= (3 * window.innerWidth) / 4) 
        {
          caixaDireitaBaixo.style.backgroundColor = 'tomato'
        }
        else
        {
          caixaMeioBaixo.style.backgroundColor = 'tomato'
        }
      }
  }
  else if (document.querySelector('.general-content3') !== null) 
  {
    //alert('sim')
      if (data == null) {
        return;
      }

      /*ConstantesFotografia vertical-----------------------------------*/
      const caixaEsquerdaCimaV = document.querySelector('#caixa-esquerda-cima');
      const caixaDireitaCimaV = document.querySelector('#caixa-direita-cima');
      const caixaEsquerdaBaixoV = document.querySelector('#caixa-esquerda-baixo');
      const caixaDireitaBaixoV = document.querySelector('#caixa-direita-baixo');

      caixaEsquerdaCimaV.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
      caixaDireitaCimaV.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
      caixaEsquerdaBaixoV.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
      caixaDireitaBaixoV.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';

      //Se o y< ecrã /2 significa que está na parte de cima 
      if (data.y <= window.innerHeight / 2)
      {
        if (data.x <= window.innerWidth / 2) 
        {
          caixaEsquerdaCimaV.style.backgroundColor = 'tomato';
        }
        else
        {
          caixaDireitaCimaV.style.backgroundColor = 'tomato';
        }

      }
      //Se o y > ecrã /2 significa que está na parte de cima
      else
      {
        if (data.x <= window.innerWidth / 2)
        {
          caixaEsquerdaBaixoV.style.backgroundColor = 'tomato';
        }
        else
        {
          caixaDireitaBaixoV.style.backgroundColor = 'tomato';
        }
      }
  }
  else
  {
    if (data == null) {
      return;
    }

    var xprediction = data.x; //these x coordinates are relative to the viewport
    var yprediction = data.y; //these y coordinates are relative to the viewport
    console.log(elapsedTime); //elapsed time is based on time since begin was called
  }



}).begin();
```